# How to create a User view using a table in database management system?

Tags: database

How to create a user view using a table in database management system?

How can we write it in SQL code?

I tried to do this...CREATE VIEW VIEW3 AS SELECT MGRSSN, FNAME, LNAME, BDATE, SALARY FROM DEPARTMENT, EMPLOYEE WHERE DEPARTMENT.MGRSSN = EMPLOYEE.SSN ;

Comment: What design do you have in mind, if you attempted to put something out I'm sure someone would be willing to help your design.

Comment: I tried to do this...CREATE VIEW VIEW3 AS
SELECT MGRSSN, FNAME, LNAME, BDATE, SALARY
FROM DEPARTMENT, EMPLOYEE
WHERE DEPARTMENT.MGRSSN = EMPLOYEE.SSN ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your exact table structure I cannot help you perform the query 100% but this should get you in the right direction and solve your issue:

**The CREATE VIEW Syntax:**

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
```

**You're performing a JOIN incorrectly:**

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW3 AS SELECT MGRSSN, FNAME, LNAME, BDATE, 
SALARY FROM DEPARTMENT, EMPLOYEE WHERE DEPARTMENT.MGRSSN = EMPLOYEE.SSN;
```

**Should look like:**

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW3
AS SELECT MGRSSN, FNAME, LNAME, BDATE, SALARY  
FROM DEPARTMENT a, EMPLOYEE b
WHERE a.MGRSSN = b.SSN
```

**You just have to query it:**

```
SELECT * FROM [VIEW3]
```

For further reading I suggest you look in the SQL documentation for CREATE VIEW statements and learn how to work with the virtual table.